# How to know the package name in apt-get install <packageName>?

Tags: installation, apt, package-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I find packages to install via apt-get](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4477/how-do-i-find-packages-to-install-via-apt-get)

We use this command to install packages on our system...

Common Syntax:

```
sudo apt-get install <packageName>
```

For example...

```
sudo apt-get install g++
```

Now in this case it was easy as we new the 1-word name "g++".

But some times this `<packageName>` differes from the actual name of the program or the actual name consists of 2 or more words like "NVIDIA X Server Settings"...

But the command is:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-settings
```

My question is:

How do people come to know that `nvidia-settings` is the required `<packageName>` for `NVIDIA X Server Settings`?

Is there any standard way to know the `<packageName>` for the desired program?

EDIT:
For example if I want to install Google chrome then how can I know that what should be replaced by `<packagename>`?:

```
sudo apt-get install <packageName>
```