# Ubuntu 11.10 Unable to locate package

Tags: 11.10, likewise

I try type in command line

```
sudo apt-get install likewise-open
```

to join a domain, but i get an output sound like this:

```
Unable to locate package likewise-open
```

Any help please..

Comment: Check [this][1] post. I think the ideas there might be a help.


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/4477/how-do-i-find-packages-to-install-via-apt-get

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to run apt-get update first. Also it'll be better if you can provide your  source.list by running `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` in terminal . So that we can see if there are something missing in your package source.

For now,  you can try something  like this.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install likewise-open
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below lines in /etc/source.list file excluding brackets.

[deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security main universe]

then use [apt-get update] to update the database & then follow below process to take your system into domain.

Please follow below steps to take Linux Desktop OS in Windows Domain.

In the Green latters all are commands and need to be followed as they are.
In the Orange letters all are Original file contents and need to be as they are.
In the Purple letters all are modified file contents and need to be as they are.

•   Login as root
o   If unable to login as root follow below steps to enable root account.
o   Login as default account that was created at the time of installation or use any other local admin account that you know of, to login.
o   Now open a terminal & type below commands and hit enter after each command
   sudo su –
(Enter the password of the accout that you used to login.)
   Now you should be root on the terminal window.
   Now enter below command
   passwd
   Enter only passwd & nothing else with it.
   It will ask you to enter new password for root.
   Enter the password of your choice.
   This will enable the root account.
o   Now to remove default user (that we created while installation) & other unwanted admin users, from admin group, enter below commands.
   usermod username –G username
   Follow the above command for all the unwanted admin users.

•   Now restart the system and login as root.

•   Login to firewall with BD ID

•   Please select all the options of the first and last tab of the Source list Option, to do that please follow below mentioned steps.
o   Open “Ubuntu Software Center” find it from start button search or icon is by default pined to the task bar.
o   Now press “Alt” button & keep it pressed to view menu options at the top of the screen (Not window).
o   Now go to “Edit” & click on “Software Sources”, which is the last option.
o   First & Default tab is “Ubuntu Software”, select all the options except one at the end i.e. “Cdrom with Ubuntu (version)”.
o   On this same tab, we have to set “Download from:” to “Main server”.
o   Now go to second tab i.e. “Other Software”, select all options and click on “Close”.
o   Close the “Ubuntu Software Center”.

•   Now we will install LikeWise
o   Please follow all below steps to install LikeWise.
o   Open the “Ubuntu Software Center”.
o   Type likewise in the search bar on the top right corner & hit enter.
o   It will show you the list of all packages related to likewise, & select and click on install for all below mentioned Packages.
   Desktop utility for joining Active Directory domains
likewise-open-gui
   Authentication services for Active Directory domains
likewise-open
   transitional dummy package
likewise-open5
   transitional dummy package
likewise-open5-eventlog
   transitional dummy package
likewise-open5-gui
   transitional dummy package
likewise-open5-libs
   transitional dummy package
likewise-open5-lsass
   transitional dummy package
likewise-open5-netlogon
   transitional dummy package
likewise-open5-rpc
o   Check if all of them are installed or not on the same page as install progress will stop on those packages & remove button will appear at the same place.
o   Once that is done close the “Ubuntu Software Center”.

•   Edit “/etc/hosts” & Enter below two lines in it. (DO NOT MAKE ANY OTHER CHANGES AS IT IS VERY IMPORTANT FILE FOR BOOTING LINUX SYSTEM)
o   Please follow below steps to do it
o   Open a terminal
o   vi /etc/hosts
o   i
   #Active Directory / OR / Domain Controler IP                      Complete Domain Name
   127.0.0.1              localhost
   127.0.0.1              (hostname of the system without brackets & spaces)
   (ip_of_DC_Server)         (Domain_Name)
o   :wq

•   Edit “/etc/nsswitch.conf” & modify below one line in it. (DO NOT MAKE ANY OTHER CHANGES AS IT IS VERY IMPORTANT FILE FOR BOOTING LINUX SYSTEM)
o   Please follow below steps to do it.
o   Open a terminal
o   vi /etc/nsswitch.conf
o   i
   (Original line is below which we will modify)
o   hosts: files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4
   (Change above mentioned line to)
o   hosts: files dns [NOTFOUND=return]
o   :wq

•   Edit “/etc/sudoers”
o   Open terminal
o   vi /etc/sudoers
o   i
   Enter one line after below shown line in this file.

## Members of the admin group may gain root privileges

%admin                ALL=(ALL) ALL
%Domain_name\administrators                 ALL=(ALL) ALL

   Once this is done, follow below commands to save and exit.
o   :wq

•   Now restart the system and login as root.

•   Now open the likewise using search option of the start menu.

•   Fill in the details in the form and click on the Join button, it will show you that it is “successfully able to join the domain” or something like it.

•   Once you see that message restart the system and you should be able to login with any domain user.